# How do I set SFTP servers check user IP when authenticating?

Tags: sftp

How do I set a SFTP server to only allow users to authenticate from a specific IP?

Comment: I've re-written your question so it's no longer opinion based. You likely need to provide the version of a sftp server your using.to be able to provide specific answers of how to configure it.

Comment: What SFTP server software are you using? Are these users using an ssh key or a password to authenticate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options (there is maybe more but these seem the simplest).

1. Configure firewalling on your server to only allow you to connect from a specific IP - However this will be user-ambiguous (It would allow *any* user from a specific IP) unless you're using a fancy firewall which also does user inspection. How to do this depends on the specific firewall you are using but generally it's pretty simple to configure access from an IP, to a specific port.
2. Directly configuring this connectivity in the sftp server itself, This will depend on the sftp server being used, and the functionality it offers.